# System.AggregateException in the client.GetAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

I am trying call the third party api in the Controller of the ASP.NET Web API I am creating.Below is the code

```
   public string Get(string Name)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string BaseURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];
            Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL);
            client.BaseAddress = uri;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            string clarity_URL = BaseURL+"api/v2/hhgh?name="+Name;
            var response = client.GetAsync(c_URL).Result;
            string responseString;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
               return responseString;
```

I am getting error in the `var response = client.GetAsync(clarity_URL).Result;` as the System.AggregateException

[image]

When I expanded the InnerException

`{"An error occurred while sending the request."}`
`{"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."}`
`{"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."}`

Comment: Expand that collection(with count 1) and you will see something

Comment: Look at the inner exception to see what the real exception is. AggregateException is a wrapper.

Comment: I have edited the question with the exception messages

Comment: "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"
pretty self explanatory. The third party needs to update their cert

Comment: If the server you are trying to connect to only supports TLS 1.2 or higher you need to add this before you create client. System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

Comment: @Hakunamatata I tried to add the code but still I get the same error